# Does jQuery's show() method work on tables in IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a table with some of the rows starting off hidden (`display:none`) and I'm using jQuery to show them. I've gathered from Firebug that jQuery detects that they're table rows and sets them to `display:table-row` rather than block.

However, IE6 (and I think 7, too) doesn't support `table-row`, so does jQuery do something different for those browsers?

Another problem seems to be using any function other than `show()` causes 100% CPU in Linux for Firefox and Chrome and they become unresponsive until I get a warning about a slow script. In Opera, the rows emerge very slowly, one by one. Is there a way to make the rows appear smoothly the same way as a normal `<div>` would?

Comment: If you have to use tables then have you tired animating the rows? -- http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate. I don't know if that affects the CPU usage more than show though.

Comment: Using `animate( {height:'show'} )` has the same problem; I guess it's doing the same thing. Also when I stop the script in Firefox, it turns out the rows are all set to `display:block` so the other effects may not be working properly anyway...

Comment: you could wrap your content in the td in a div and then show or hide that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible. The reason is that a table-row doesn't have layout. It is strictly a structure element not a display element. The table-data is neither a display element, it's a structure element as well. You can however try this. This will hide the contents of the table-data, effectively collapsing the table row.

```
// show
$("table tr.show").find("td *").show();
// hide
$("table tr.hide").find("td *").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me (assuming the TR has "display:none" set):

> $("#table_row").css("display","table-row");
>
> if($("#table_row").css("display")=="none")
>
> $("#table_row").css("display","block");

IE doesn't recognize the table-row attribute, so instead of changing the display value, it retains whatever value it previously had (in this case "none"). So all you have to do is test whether display changed to table-row (FF & Chrome) or it retained its previous value (IE).

Hope this helped.